# The sum of the same values in a field next to each other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
const data = [ 250, 250, 500, 500 ]
const labels = [ '2022-05-10', '2022-06-10', '2022-07-10', '2022-07-10' ]
```

Each date in the `labels` array has a corresponding value in the `data` array, and I need to sum the values for each day that's the same, so the output should look like this:

```
const data = [ 250, 250, 1000 ]
const labels = [ '2022-05-10', '2022-06-10', '2022-07-10' ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: perhaps a reduce?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const labels = ['2022-05-10', '2022-06-10', '2022-07-10', '2022-07-10'];
const data = [250, 250, 500, 500];

const restructure = (keysArray, valuesArray) => 
    keysArray.reduce((accumu, current, index) => {
      current = { [current]: valuesArray[index] };
      for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(current)) {
        accumu[key] = (accumu[key] ?? 0) + val;
      }
      return accumu;
    }, {});

const prettyPrint = (title, obj) => 
    console.log(`${title} =>`, JSON.stringify(obj));

const result = restructure(labels, data);

prettyPrint('labels', Object.keys(result));
prettyPrint('data', Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [ 250, 250, 500, 500 ];
const labels = [ '2022-05-10', '2022-06-10', '2022-07-10', '2022-07-10' ];

var newData = new Array();
var newLabels = new Array();

labels.forEach(myFunction);    
newLabels.forEach(myFunction2);

function myFunction(item,index) {
    console.log(item + ',' + index);
    if(!newLabels.includes(item) ) {
       newLabels.push(item);
       newData.push(data[index]);
    }
    else {
        var newIndex = newLabels.indexOf(item);
        console.log(newIndex);
        var added = newData[newIndex] + data[index];
        newData[newIndex] = added;
    }
}

function myFunction2(item,index){
   console.log(item + ',' + index);
   console.log(newData[index]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My javascript is pretty rusty, but this zips the two arrays together, and then creates an object where I add to the object if that key already exists, or create it if it doesn't. (That might be what a proper `reduce` answer does?)

```js
zip = (...rows) => [...rows[0]].map((_, c) => rows.map(row => row[c]))

let data = [250, 250, 500, 500]
let labels = ['2022-05-10', '2022-06-10', '2022-07-10', '2022-07-10']

const values = zip(labels, data)
const output = {}
for (const [date, value] of values) {
   if (Object.keys(output).includes(date)) {
      output[date] += value
   }
   else {
      output[date] = value
   }
}
data = Object.values(output)
labels = Object.keys(output)
console.log(data)
console.log(labels)
```